# Can you emulate "set -e" and "set -x" via the environment?

Tags: shell, automake, sh

Many of my test scripts begin:

```
set -e
test -n "$V" && set -x
```

Rather than putting those lines ( or sourcing a common script ) in each script, I'd
like to get that functionality through the environment.  Is there a portable way to use environment settings to cause sh to behave as if "set -e" or "set -x" has been called?  Is there a non-portable (ie shell-specific) way to do the same?

(I've tagged this question as automake because that's the framework I'm in at the moment and would like to be able to put something in TESTS_ENVIRONMENT that will allow me to omit those lines from each script, but clearly the question is not automake specific.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the automake part.

If you have

```
TESTS = foo.test bar.test baz.test
```

the `Makefile` generated will have a `test` target roughly like

```
test:
        ...
        $(TEST_ENVIRONMENT) $(srcdir)/foo.test
        $(TEST_ENVIRONMENT) $(srcdir)/bar.test
        $(TEST_ENVIRONMENT) $(srcdir)/baz.test
        ...
```

You can actually set `TEST_ENVIRONMENT` to a command that will start your shell scripts with `sh -xe` or `sh -e`.

If all tests are shell scripts, this can be a simple as setting

```
TEST_ENVIRONMENT = $(SHELL) -e $${V+-x}
```

if not all tests are shell scripts, you can have

```
TEST_ENVIRONMENT = $(srcdir)/run
```

and write a script `run` such as:

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1 in
  *.py)
    exec python "$@";;
  *.test)
    exec sh -x ${V+-x} "$@";;
  *)
    echo "Unknown extension" >&2
    exit 2;;
esac
```

Comment: That's what I wanted!  Great idea.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this to your scripts:

```
eval "${ENABLE_DEBUG}"
```

Now you can set the env variable `ENABLE_DEBUG` to `set -e ; test -n "$V" && set -x` to enable debugging or you can leave it unset.

Note that this fails if you have the option "fail for undefined variables" active (`set -u` or `set -o nounset`). If that is the case, you either need to check that the variable is set or use bash with:

```
eval "${ENABLE_DEBUG}"
```

that sets the variable to `:`, the "do nothing" command.

Comment: Nice trick. One caveat though: `${ENABLE_DEBUG}` is fine when `ENABLE_DEBUG` is set simply to e.g. `set -e`; but to use a more complex construct (like you provided) you'd have to use `eval "${ENABLE_DEBUG}"`. Also make sure you don't have anything weird in your `$IFS`.

Comment: I need `eval` because of the `;`, right? Hmmm.. Well, `eval ""` doesn't give an error.

Comment: Right, because of the `;` and `&&` and `$`. Basically, after the parameter substitution, only field splitting and filename generation occur.

Comment: That's a good idea.  You can avoid the set -u problem by doing 'eval "${ENABLE_DEBUG:-:}"'